# Как поставить WordPress не с корневой папки?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Задача такая, есть сайт https://site.net Сайт из себе представляет набор html страниц. К сайту необходимо подключить блог с которым будут работать копирайторы. Вопрос, как правильно установить WP в папку /blog/ ?
То есть переходя на https://site.net/blog/ должен попадать уже на главную WP.
Папку я создал, WP туда залил... подскажите какие настройки надо писать в базу WP и собственно .htaccess Что б оно запустилось ? Сейчас .htaccess выглядит так

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Директивы (строки) между `BEGIN WordPress` и `END WordPress`
# созданы автоматически и подлежат изменению только через фильтры WordPress.
# Сделанные вручную изменения между этими маркерами будут перезаписаны.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Ничего больше не надо

Answer (score 0):

Можно в wp-config.php прописать адрес блога

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://site.net/blog/');

define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://site.net/blog/');
```

Comment: Зачем? Чтобы поиметь доп геммороев при миграции?

Comment: даже немалую кучку..